# Grails with ldap authentication

Tags: grails, ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'm trying to integrate grails app with ldap authentication using grails spring ldap plugin. here is my confing

```
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDN = 'CN=acc,DC=two,DC=three'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'correctpassword'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldaps://server:636'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'OU=one,DC=two,DC=three'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter='sAMAccountName={0}'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.prefix = "ROLE_"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.defaultRole = "ADMIN"
```

every time i tried to log in  i recived an error

```
    pErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1 ]; nested exception is javax.naming.Authentic
ationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e,
 v1db1 ]
```

i have checked and it means that credentials are invalid, but thats not true.
Then i check what will happen if i change `correctpassword` to inncorect one, and same error happens, is tere something wrong with my configuration ? is there any atrribute missing? My login controler is default controler, i use `secured` annotations for controllers with restricted access

Comment: Try changing `search.filter` to something like `grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter='(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))'` Where objectCategory is correct category from your AD

Comment: ok, i will, but in ldap seraching with filter sAMAccountName=name gives correct results

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference as this just adds additional filter, but it solved the same issue for us. Maybe parenthesis or something else are needed for just sAMAccountName. Sorry if it doesn't help you.

Comment: @droggo coudl you post your comment as answer? it was good solution, anyway who coudl know? at official page of grails plugin spring security ldap filters are without parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter=sAMAccountName={0}` to something like `grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter='(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAcc‌​ountName={0}))` Where objectCategory is correct category from your AD

It shouldn't make a difference as this just adds additional filter, but it solved the same issue for us. Maybe parenthesis or category filter are needed for this property